# How to active tab in Angular Bootstrap UI after change route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have used **tab component** in [Angular Bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for routing in my Angularjs app.

Now I want to active one of tabs, after change route. In fact I have a search route and I want to change tabs due to the **search options** (that users can select where they want to search).

Comment: Use `$stateParams` for that to get passed parameter. And define the parameter `url: '/entity/list?param1&param2` in a route if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem!

If each tab has exclusive route, we can use [angular ui router sticky](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky) to handle this.

*use bootstrap*

**users.pug**

```
ul.nav.nav-tabs

    li.nav-item(ui-sref-active-eq='active')
       a.nav-link(ui-sref="users") users list

    li.nav-item(ui-sref-active-eq='active')
       a.nav-link(ui-sref="users.newUser") newUser

.tab-content(ui-view="usersTab")
```

**usersList.pug**

```
h1 users list page
```

**newuser.pug**

```
h1 new user page
```

**route.js**

```
.state('users', {
    url: '/users',
    templateUrl: 'users.html',
    controller: 'usersCtrl'
})
.state('usersList', {
    url: '/usersList',
    sticky: true,
    views: {
       "usersTab": {
           templateUrl: 'usersList.html',
           controller: 'usersListCtrl'
       }
    }
})
.state('newUser', {
    url: '/newUser',
    sticky: true,
    views: {
       "usersTab": {
           templateUrl: 'newUser.html',
           controller: 'newUserCtrl'    
       }
    }

})
```

And to active each tab can use: `ui-sref-active-eq='active'` and `.active` class change active tab style